# Having an issue converting SQL to postgreSQL with ''' making huge strings

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
CONCAT('ERROR - Portfolio '', ''' not found in br_portfolio and composite_member table')
```

My issue is that ''' is creating a huge string that goes on for many lines after it is, so I guess the problem is how do I create ' char as a string that is wrapped in ''?

Thanks

Comment: Double it, e.g. `'ERROR - Portfolio '''` will and with a single `'`.

Comment: BTW, the above CONCAT code has invalid syntax. `not` comes directly after a string.

Comment: Not is supposed to be part of the string the original SQL arument looked like this

Comment: It looks like you're trying to concatenate two strings. Does the first string have a single `'` as its last character? How does the second string start?

Comment: Not is supposed to be part of the string the original SQL argument looked like this

"ERROR - Portfolio '" + ''' not found in br_portfolio and composite_member table"

Comment: Are you coming from SQL Server? Skip the concat attempt, and simply use the `||` concatenation operator instead of SQL Server's `+`.

Comment: Thnaks for all the help but still having issues using the || operator I am getting one large string as it stilll cant tell when I want to use ' as char

Comment: Use two single-quotes to represent a single-quote. E.g. `'abc''de'` will give you `abc'de`.

Comment: How about?: `select CONCAT('ERROR - Portfolio ', 'not found in br_portfolio and composite_member table');`. If that is not the answer  you will need to add, as update to question, the desired output string.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is more of a comment, but for what it's worth some additional options for you.

If you have a long string that includes return characters and single quotes, you can always use string literals using $$:

```
select $ONE$I'm a dog$ONE$, $FOOT$Hello,
Hambone's Dog$FOOT$
```

Hopefully you can see what goes inside the $$ doesn't matter -- it just has to match the beginning and end of the literal.

Second comment:  I really like the `format` function in Pg.  It's cleaner, in my opinion, than doing concat or multiple concat operators:

```
select format ('Eating too much %s is dangerous', 'cake')
```

So, combining these two, I wonder if this will help make your code cleaner/easier:

```
create table test (portfolio varchar(20));

insert into test values ('foot'), ('ball');

select
  format ($EE$ERROR - Portfolio '%s' not found in br_portfolio$EE$, portfolio)
from test;
```